# Is it faster to get variables via ajax response or use .load() to load a php page

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a search function that returns 100 orders out of a large database and I am trying to reduce the load time. Is it quicker to do:

```
$( '#orders' ).load( "myScript.php", { var1:x, var2:y, var3:z } );
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "JSON", 
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://url.com",
    data: data,
    success: function( res ) {
        var orders = "<table>";
        for (var i = 0; i < res['orders'].length; i++) {
            orders += "<tr><td>order id</td><td>" + res['orders'][i]['id'] + "</td></tr>";
            orders += "<tr><td>price</td><td>" + res['orders'][i]['price'] + "</td></tr>";
            //etc
            //etc
            //etc
        }
        orders += "</table>";

        document.getElementById( 'orders' ).innerHTML = orders;
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be quickest to return JSON from the server and process that in to a UI structure on the client. Exactly how you make that AJAX request is moot to this.

Comment: Both mentioned methods are using AJAX.

Comment: Why don't you time it 

`var t0 = performance.now();

doSomething();   // <---- The function you're measuring time for 

var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
`

Comment: as @Teemu said both methods use ajax so both method will have similar performances

Comment: Are you trying to compare the difference between rendering the HTML on the server side vs sending the data and creating the HTML in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of `myScript.php` compared to the size of the `JSON` data. Whichever is larger will take more time. 
It also depends on how the data is serialized.